# My hat doesn't show up on meta. Why?

Tags: bug

My hat doesn't show up on [meta](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com).

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hats are not enabled for META as far as I know, and it doesn't appear there are any plans to change that any time soon.

Comment: oops, right, thanks...